# C# Flat ellipse arc angle

Tags: c#, drawing, ellipse

I've got a problem with drawing arc of flat ellipse at given angle.

I've got some simple programing code in C# with arc of circle and ellipse at given angle:

```
        Graphics GRP = this.CreateGraphics();

        Pen PEN = new Pen(Color.Red);

        // Angle
        float Start = 358f;
        float Sweep = 180f;

        // Circle
        GRP.DrawArc(PEN, new Rectangle(75, 75, 200, 200), Start, Sweep);

        // Ellipse
        GRP.DrawArc(PEN, new Rectangle(75, 75, 200, 10), Start, Sweep);
```

So my start angle is 358°, a litle less than 360° and sweep angle 180°.

I haven't got a problem with circle, but the different situation is with flat ellipse - the whole ellipse rotates towards 270° - flatter ellipse results more rotation ([disance is represented by X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QygLR.png)).

I couldn't find any posts about this problem...I need precise ellipse arc for my program.

I would realy appreciate for any help and apologise for my english =)

Comment: im confused as to what the desired result is.

Comment: The coordinate system is inverted.  (0, 0) is at the upper left corner.  So 90 degrees is **down**, not up.  And never use CreateGraphics, use Paint.